# Separating single column of data into multiple columns but single row

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, office365

https://gist.github.com/SirChurchill9999/1baee3adc055d8c1c76ca2f2be417c8f

```
Leanne Hazard
1. Leanne Hazard
Expert Witness AR
Position: Forensic Toxicologist
Areas of Expertise: Medical & Surgical - Toxicology; Employment & Vocational - Forensics
Expert Evaluator Report
James M. Pape, M.D.
2.James M. Pape, M.D.
Expert Witness AR
Position: Orthopedic Surgeon
Areas of Expertise: Medical & Surgical - Surgery -- General; Medical & Surgical - Orthopedics
Expert Evaluator Report
Wayne E. Williams
3. Wayne E. Williams
Expert Witness AR
Position: Forestry Expert
Areas of Expertise: Environmental - Trees
Expert Challenge Report 
Expert Evaluator Report
```

I am trying to move the grouped items into separate columns but all aligned with the person's name.... for example:

Leanne Hazard ..... 1. Leanne Hazard ...... Expert Witness AR ...... Position: Forensic Toxicologist

The issue I've run into is that some of these groups end with "expert evaluator report" and others with "expert challenge report." See the above code for an example.

Comment: It appears that all records consist of exactly 6 lines though, is that true for the entire dataset?

Comment: The last record, Wayne E. Williams, is unfortunately 7 lines. There's no rhyme or reason when a record = 6 lines versus 7 lines. Just that some of them contain an "expert challenge report" as well

Comment: Ah apologies. that's clear from the data - the colouring threw me off. Every record ends in 'Expert Evaluator Report' though - in your text you suggested that some end with "Expert Challenge Report". Do you mean to say that some records not show here end in "Expert Challenge Report", without "Expert Evaluator Report"?

Answer (score 0):

Since a record appears to always end in 'Expert Evaluator Report':

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SirChurchill9999/1baee3adc055d8c1c76ca2f2be417c8f/raw/25a05aad8ee315f20970ac3af20b21bf1231b97b/Sample.xlsx') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            record = [next(f).decode().strip() for __ in range(6)]
            if record[-1] != 'Expert Evaluator Report':
                record.append(next(f).decode().strip())
            print(record)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Result:

```
['Leanne Hazard', '1. Leanne Hazard', 'Expert Witness\xa0AR', 'Position:\xa0Forensic Toxicologist', 'Areas of Expertise:\xa0Medical & Surgical - Toxicology; Employment & Vocational - Forensics', 'Expert Evaluator Report']
['James M. Pape, M.D.', '2.James M. Pape, M.D.', 'Expert Witness\xa0AR', 'Position:\xa0Orthopedic Surgeon', 'Areas of Expertise:\xa0Medical & Surgical - Surgery -- General; Medical & Surgical - Orthopedics', 'Expert Evaluator Report']
['Wayne E. Williams', '3. Wayne E. Williams', 'Expert Witness\xa0AR', 'Position:\xa0Forestry Expert', 'Areas of Expertise:\xa0Environmental - Trees', 'Expert Challenge Report', 'Expert Evaluator Report']
```

Your file has the extension `.xlsx`, but appears to be a regular text file?

Comment: Grismar, thank you so much for your help. You are correct that each report ends in "expert evaluator report." The data on GitHub is copied and pasted from my Excel file - GitHub just said to add the appropriate file ending so I added .xlsx.

Comment: Grismar, I created a new thread because of a decoding error I ran into. Let me know if you have a few minutes to check it out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685133/converting-single-xlsx-column-to-separate-rows-python-excel